# Prohibit auto rotation for one component in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autorotate

Is it possible to prohibit auto rotation for one component in Swift?
I want my iPad to rotate but the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` should not rotate. 
So is it possible to prohibit the rotation for this layer?

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to implement the rotation callbacks and rotate the layer yourself to the position the screen was before.

it would look something like this

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size 

withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{

[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {

         UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

         if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            /// rotate layer to old orientation

         }else{
             /// rotate layer to old orientation
         }

     } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {


     }];


}
```